What is the minimum value of $a+b-c$ in a triangle with a fixed area?
Let $\Delta$ be the fixed area of a triangle inscribed inside on a fixed circle of radius $R$. The sides of the triangle $(a,b,c)$ are unknown. We want to estimate a the lower bound of the triangle inequality $a+b-c$ in terms of $\Delta$ and $R$. I obtained the following estimate experimentally. Can it be proved or disproved?
$$
a+b-c \ge \frac{\Delta}{2R} + \frac{43 - 3\sqrt{17}}{112}\cdot\frac{\Delta^2}{R^3}
$$
Related question: Does every triangle satisfy $(a+b-c) \ge 8s\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}C_k \left(\frac{A}{s^2}\right)^{2k}$?

Just "thinking out loud" ... Defining $D:=\Delta$ to save typing, we have
$$\begin{align}D&=2r^2\sin A\sin B\sin(A+B) \tag1\ a+b-c&=\frac{D}{2r}\sec\tfrac12A\sec\tfrac12B\sec\tfrac12(A+B)\tag2\end{align}$$ Eliminating, say, angle $B$, this reduces to a one-parameter optimization problem. If(!) my hasty analysis in Mathematica is accurate, the optimal value of $(2)$ (call it $x$) is encoded in this octic polynomial:
$$x^8-16r^2x^6+160Drx^5+32D^2x^4-2048Dr^3x^3+3072D^2r^2x^2-1536D^3rx+256D^4=0$$ This may-or-may-not help with finding bounds on $x$.

@Blue How did you get that Octic equation? Can you post it as an answer?

"Can you post it as an answer?" Done! :)

Potential hint: By Heron's formula, $16\Delta^2 = (a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)$.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcircle
$$ 
2R = \frac{abc}{2\Delta}\leftrightarrow \frac{4R\Delta}{ab}=c (+)
$$
and when $R$ and $\Delta$ are given then
$$
a+b-c = a+b-\frac{4R\Delta}{ab}.
$$
To minimize the value set the partial derivatives $\partial/\partial a$, $\partial/\partial b$ to zero
$$
1+\frac{4R\Delta}{a^2b}=0;\quad
1+\frac{4R\Delta}{ab^2}=0;\quad
$$
which yields $a=b$ (isoceless) imaginary values. The symmetry suggests
that nevertheless $a=b$ is a valid conjecture.
By Euclid's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_triangle in a triangle of altitude $h=\sqrt{a^2-(c/2)^2}$
the area is half the baseline times the altitude,
$$
\Delta=\frac12 c\sqrt{a^2-c^2/4}.
$$
$$
\Delta=\frac14 c^2\sqrt{4(a/c)^2-1}
$$
$$
\frac{4\Delta}{c^2}=\sqrt{4(a/c)^2-1} (++)
$$
According to (+)
$$
\frac12 c\sqrt{a^2-c^2/4}
= \frac{1}{4R}a^2c
$$
$$
2R \sqrt{a^2-c^2/4}
= a^2
$$
$$
Rc \sqrt{4(a/c)^2-1}
= a^2
$$
$$
\frac{R}{c} \sqrt{4(a/c)^2-1}
= (a/c)^2 
$$
$$
\frac{R}{c}
= \frac{(a/c)^2 }{\sqrt{4(a/c)^2-1}}
$$
$$
\frac{R^2}{c^2}
= \frac{(a/c)^4 }{4(a/c)^2-1} (+++)
$$
Divide (++) by (+++) and set $(a/c)^2=x$,
$$
\frac{4\Delta}{R^2} = \frac{(4x-1)^{3/2}}{x^2}.
$$
$$
(\frac{4\Delta}{R^2})^2 x^4 = (4x-1)^3.
$$
As a shortcut set $t=(\Delta/R^2)^{2/3}$,
$$
16 t^3 x^4 = (4x-1)^3.
$$
This quartic equation for $x$ must in principle be solved numerically.
The circumcircle area $\pi R^2$ is larger than the triangle area $\Delta$.
So alternatively one can solve the quartic equation in a series of $t$,
$$
x\approx \frac{1}{4}+\frac{2^{2/3}}{16}t+\frac{2^{1/3}}{24}t^2
+\frac{1}{32}t^3
+\frac{65\cdot 2^{2/3}}{5184} t^4
+\frac{1309\cdot 2^{1/3}}{124416}t^5
+\frac{7}{768}t^6
+\cdots
$$
Then
$c=R\sqrt{4x-1}/x$, and
$$
a+b-c=2a-c=c(2\sqrt{x}-1)
=R\frac{\sqrt{4x-1}}{x}(2\sqrt{x}-1) =
$$
$$
R[\frac12 t^{3/2} +3\frac{2^{2/3}}{32}t^{5/2}+7\frac{2^{1/3}}{128}t^{7/2}+\frac{233}{6144}t^{9/2}+\frac{2^{2/3}\cdot 6391}{442368}t^{11/2}\cdots]
$$
$$
=R[\frac12 \frac{\Delta}{R^2}+3\frac{2^{2/3}}{32}(\Delta/R^2)^{5/3}+\cdots].
$$
Comparison of the leading 5 terms of this expansion of $a+b-c$ in powers of $t^{1/3}$
with the 2 terms of the expansion of $a+b-c$ in powers of $t$
in the lower bound in the question: The 5 terms give a slightly smaller value for $0.5<t<0.88$  (so the inequality
in the question seems to be violated by the order of one percent), but because the neglected terms in the expansion of $t^{1/3}$ have
positive coefficients, that is only a weak argument against the proposed inequality.

Let $z = \frac{\Delta}{R^2}$. You have obtained a nice series (+1) of the form $$a+b-c = a_1Rz + a_2R z^{5/3} + a_3R z^{7/3} + \cdots$$ This is slightly different from the original question which asks if there is a series of the form $$a+b-c = b_1Rz + b_2R z^{2} + b_3R z^{3} + \cdots$$ Notice that since $z <1$ is a dimensionless quantity, we can have more than one arithmetical series $p, p+r, p+2r,\cdots$ such that $$a+b-c = a_1Rz^p + a_2R z^{p+r} + a_2R z^{p+2r} + \cdots$$.

Expanding a comment ...
Defining $x:=(a+b-c)/2$ (division by $2$ makes coefficients slightly nicer later), we start with these equations:
$$\begin{align}
\Delta &= 2r^2\sin A\,\sin B\,\sin(A+B) \tag1 \\[4pt]
\Delta &= 4rx\cos\tfrac12 A\cos\tfrac12B\cos\tfrac12(A+B) \tag2
\end{align}$$
One can show that symmetry implies that any optimal solution occurs in an isosceles triangle, with $A=B$; in this case, the equations become
$$\begin{align}
\Delta &= 2r^2\sin^2 A\sin2A &&=4r^2\sin A\cos A(1-\cos^2A)\tag3 \\[4pt]
\Delta &= 4rx\cos^2\tfrac12 A\cos A &&=2rx\cos A(1+\cos A)\tag4
\end{align}$$
so that "all we have to do" is eliminate references to $A$. Squaring $(3)$ and substituting $\sin^2A\to1-\cos^2A$ gives us two polynomial equations in $\cos A$. Using, say, the method of resultants (in the form of Mathematica's Resultant function), we eliminate that term to obtain
$$x^8 - 4 r^2 x^6 + 20 \Delta r x^5 + 2 \Delta^2 x^4 - 64 \Delta r^3 x^3 + 48 \Delta^2 r^2 x^2 - 12 \Delta^3 r x + \Delta^4 = 0 \tag5$$
This may-or-may-not be useful for improving OP's bounds on $x$ (or, rather, $2x$).
